# Case insensitive where clause in gql query for StringProperty

Tags: google-app-engine, gql, gqlquery

Using the google appengine datastore, is there a way to perform a gql query that specifies a WHERE clause on a StringProperty datatype that is case insensitive?  I am not always sure what case the value will be in.  The docs specify that the where is case sensitive for my values, is there a way to make this insensitive?

for instance the db Model would be this:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
class Product(db.Model):
    id = db.IntegerProperty()
    category = db.StringProperty()
```

and the data looks like this:

```
id         category
===================
1          cat1
2          cat2
3          Cat1
4          CAT1
5          CAT3
6          Cat4
7          CaT1
8          CAT5
```

i would like to say

```
gqlstring = "WHERE category = '{0}'".format('cat1')
returnvalue = Product.gql(gqlstring)
```

and have `returnvalue` contain

```
id         category
===================
1          cat1
3          Cat1
4          CAT1
7          CaT1
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think there is an operator like that in the datastore.

Do you control the input of the category data?  If so, you should choose a canonical form to store it in (all lowercase or all uppercase).  If you need to store the original case for some reason, then you could just store two columns - one with the original, one with the standardized one.  That way you can do a normal WHERE clause.

Answer (score 6):

The datastore doesn't support case insensitive comparisons, because you can't index queries that use them (barring an index that transforms values). The solution is to store a normalized version of your string in addition to the standard one, as Peter suggests. The property classes in the [AETycoon](http://github.com/arachnid/aetycoon) library may prove helpful, in particular, DerivedProperty.

Comment: I did end up writing a script to normalize them.   Thanks for the pointer to the library.

Answer (score 0):

This thread was helpful and makes me want to contribute with similar approach to make partial search match possible. I add one more field on datastore kind and save each word on normalized phrase as a set and then use IN filter to collide. This is an example with a Clojure. Normalize part should easy translate to java at least (thanks to @raek on #clojure), while database interaction should be convertable to any language:

```
(use '[clojure.contrib.string :only [split lower-case]])
(use '[appengine-magic.services.datastore :as ds])

; initialize datastore kind entity
(ds/defentity AnswerTextfield [value, nvalue, avalue]) 

; normalize and lowercase a string
(defn normalize [string-to-normalize]
  (lower-case
    (apply str
      (remove #(= (Character/getType %) Character/NON_SPACING_MARK)
               (java.text.Normalizer/normalize string-to-normalize java.text.Normalizer$Form/NFKD)))))

; save original value, normalized value and splitted normalized value
(defn textfield-save! [value]
  (ds/save! 
    (let [nvalue (normalize value)]
      (ds/new* AnswerTextfield [value nvalue (split #" " nvalue)]))))

; normalized search
(defn search-normalized [value]
  (ds/query :kind AnswerTextfield
            :filter [(= :nvalue (normalize value))]))

; partial normalized word search
(defn search-partial [value]
  (flatten
    (let [coll []]
      (for [splitted-value (split #" " (normalize value))]
        (merge coll 
          (ds/query :kind AnswerTextfield
                    :filter [(in :avalue [splitted-value])]))))))
```