# How to uppercase or lowercase datastore field name (for eg - lastname or first of a user which was input via a web form) on GQL?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, datastore, gql

I want to retrieve a profile from GQL based on their last name which is input from the web form that the person has gone through. Since the last name that they put in can be in any case(lower or upper) , I want to convert that last name to a particular case in my GQL query to Google Cloud datastore.

the code below is what's already existing right now , but seems like 'this.kind' makes the query case sensitive and hence returns 'profile not found' whenever the cases differ

```
this.ds
      .createQuery(this.kind)
      .filter('last_name', '=', lastName);
```

Answer (score 0):

GQL is based on SQL:

https://www.gqlstandards.org

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/gqlreference#Syntax

It says that GQL are case insensitive.

> Here 's a thread about setting SQL to case insensitive:
>
> [Changing SQL Server collation to case insensitive from case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296428/changing-sql-server-collation-to-case-insensitive-from-case-sensitive)
>
> https://www.webucator.com/how-to/how-check-case-sensitivity-sql-server.cfm

Datastore don't support case-insensitive queries:

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#restrictions_on_queries

However here:

[Case insensitive where clause in gql query for StringProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658163/case-insensitive-where-clause-in-gql-query-for-stringproperty)

Was fixed using a script.